# DynamicsNav Calling a procedure from a codeunit on action button

Tags: microsoft-dynamics, navision

I've have multiple procedures in a codeunit and i want to call a certain procedure OnAction button in a page.

```
trigger OnAction();
var
<Var> : CodeUnit <CodeunitName>
begin
<Var>.<FunctionName>;
<Var>.Run;
end;
```

what I'm it doing wrong? and what is the correct one

Answer (score 0):

Just call the procedure you want and don’t call `Run`. Run is just procedure as the rest, only predefined.